# Why does memory increase after closing a form?

Tags: c#, memory, formclosing

I'm kinda new to C#. I read that closing a form instead of hiding can free memory. However, when I closed a form, it even made memory increases. To be specific, I have two form: `Form1` and `Form2`. When I log in user successfully, `Form2` will open (Memory is 20Mb). `Form2` have a button to log out user, close it and turn back to `Form1` (Memory now increases to 41Mb and continue increasing for the next user). I don't know why, is there anybody can help me? This is my code to `close` Form2:

```
private void doctorLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgBox.Image.Dispose();
    this.Dispose();
    Form1 Login = new Form1();
    Login.Show();
    this.Close();   
}
```

Comment: after close you can try disposing too by calling `Dispose` method

Comment: You are not "returning" to Form1, you are creating **a new Form1**.

Comment: As you see above, I already called `Dispose` before closing.

Comment: Did memory also increase when you did not create the new `Form1`?

Comment: I guess you'd want some sort of UIManager that keeps an instance of each Form1 and Form2 that you show/hide as approariate.

Comment: Instead of creating a new form every time you click the button, could you allocate one form at the ahead of time, preferably one that you never destroy, and just use that when you need a `Form1` object?

Comment: If you created Form2 in Form1 then there could be a reference leaking, so GC won't collect the first Form1. Same is for Form2. So each "Ping-Pong" will allocate more Memory, but no memory will be released.

Comment: As you guys said, my problem is creating a `new form` instead of calling the old one. That's why the memory always increases. I fixed it already. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void doctorLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Free image resources (may appear to be optional, but doesn't spoil anything) 
    imgBox.Image.Dispose();

    // Do we have any Form1 instances?
    Form1 Login = Application
      .OpenForms
      .OfType<Form1>()
      .LastOrDefault(); // If we have several Form1's, let's take the last one

    // Only when we haven't any Form1 instances we have to create a new one
    if (null == Login) 
      Login = new Form1(); 

    Login.Show();

    // Close (and Dispose) 
    this.Close();   
}
```

In your current code

```
...
Form1 Login = new Form1();
Login.Show();
...
```

you are creating yet another `Form1` instance while not looking for alreday created ones.

Comment: This is the great answer! Thank you so much for great help.

Answer (score 1):

Well from your description you want to go back to `Form1` that was already created but what I can see from this short piece of code you create a new Form.

```
Form1 Login = new Form1();
```

Is the old `Form1` released when you are displaying `Form2`? Maybe the old one is not properly released? The discolosed part fo code doesn't tell that.

it's too little code that you show to be sure but you can run a Memory profiler (dotMemory, ANTS Memory) and check if there are some objects left that should not be.

Comment: My problem is creating a new form instead of calling the old one. That's why the memory always increases. I fixed it already. Thanks for your help!